# Integrality Constraint and Analytical Solution for a Non-linear Optimization Problem

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, integer-programming, constraint-programming

I have been trying to solve the following non-linear optimization problem:

$$\max_{0\leq x \leq 1}  N(x\lambda-x^2c)$$

where $\lambda, c >0$.

I think the solution is the following:

If $\lambda\leq2c, \ x^*=\frac{\lambda}{2c},$
and if $\lambda>2c, \ x^*=1$.

Now, consider forcing $Nx$ to be integer to the above problem. The question is: how to obtain an analytical solution, in the presence of above integrality constraint?

Thank you.

Comment: $\lambda, c, N \in \mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: Without knowing what $N$ is, or some relevant properties, it is hard to guess what the answer might be.

Comment: Of course, $N \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, $\lambda, c \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The objective is a concave function of $x$.  If the optimal $x$ (without integrality constraint) is between $i/N$ and $(i+1)/N$, the optimal solution with that constraint will be either $i/N$ or $(i+1)/N$, whichever gives a greater objective value (if both are in the interval $[0,1]$).